# socket.io emitting to all clients works, but emitting to room doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

When I try `io.emit()`, the message gets emitted to everyone but when I try `io.to(room).emit()`, the message doesn't get emitted (In the 3rd last line of the code).

I manually checked the sockets in the room, and all are present in the room correctly. But the message never gets transmitted.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on("create game", async ( gameID, host ) => {
        socket.join(gameID);
        // some logic
    })
    socket.on("join game", async ( gameID, user ) => {
        socket.join(gameID);
        // some logic
        io.to(gameID).emit("new user", user);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using `socket.in(gameID).emit("new user", user);` instead

Answer (score 1):

Is your socket connected to a particular namespace? In my project I had on the client side the following:

```
const socket = io.connect("/play-online").
```

So in order to emit to the room I created for that, I had to do:

```
io.of("/play-online").to(room.roomName).emit("move", move);
```

Comment: If that was the issue, normal `emit()` should not work right?

Comment: i was able to fix it using `socket.in(gameID).emit("new user", user);` instead

Comment: socket.in (which is synonomous to socket.to) does not broadcast to the sender according to their documentation, so if that's not a problem, then it's all good.

Comment: Oh wow. How is it even working then :P